# Altered media sizes (in dash), not updating to existing images/posts

Tags: child-theme, images, media-settings, automation

(I have searched but not found a satisfying answer – bear with me).

- I have a client that has a website with 1500 posts. Each post
  consists of ONE image, no text.
- I have changed to the Oria theme (and made a child), and in doing
  so need **bigger** images (*scaling **down** is not a problem*).
- I altered the media sizes in the control panel, from "medium 500" to "medium 900px".

  I then ran the plugin *regenerate thumbnails..*

*`But I cannot get the images in the posts to update from the old medium (500px) to the new medium (900px).`*

(I also tried the plugin "*really regenerate thumbnails*" - no dice).

If I go into edit in the post and click the edit for the image, it says "medium 900", and if I then just click update (without touching anything) it will get the image right. But clearly: I cannot do this for 1500 images.

This kind of makes sense, as the actual code in the post looks like this:

```
<a href="http://theNameOfTheSite.net/?attachment_id=163" rel="attachment wp-att-163"><img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-163" title="snow" src="http:/theNameOfTheSite.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/IMG_1155-crop-500x500.jpg" alt=" " width="500" height="500" /></a>
```

...where this is the crux:
**....IMG_1155-crop-500x500.jpg" alt=" " width="500" height="500"**

...so **it still uses the 500x500 thumbnail (old medium setting).** Deleting that particular file is also not getting me anywhere.

I tried fixing it with css (img first child width), and that kind of works, **BUT it then takes the 500px image and upscales this to 900px which is not acceptable** (gets fuzzy).

I also tried disabling all plugins, went over every setting I could think of, deactivated Jetpacks image control, tried looking in the various php files, hoping to find a clue in functions. I am not a programmer but are fine with testing various blocks of code – if I just knew what to try.. :S

So, now I am at the point where I just want to override: some magic piece of code in my child theme function to either replace everything related to 500px, or override all images in content div with original (big) picture and downsize to 900px.

Or, am I missing something other, blindingly obvious?